# Arch Linux: error: could not find all required packages

Tags: arch-linux, aur

For the past few days I've been getting the following error when running `paru -Su`:

```
~ ❯ paru -Su        
[sudo] password for j: 
:: Starting full system upgrade...
 there is nothing to do
:: Looking for AUR upgrades...
:: Looking for devel upgrades...
:: Resolving dependencies...
error: could not find all required packages:
    ruby>=3.1 (wanted by: ruby-xdg)
```

I understand the error, I'm just not sure what to do to fix it!

Is there anything I can do? It doesn't actually specify what required packages are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just had to deal with the same error, which was blocking `paru` upgrades. I ran:

`pacman -Qi ruby-xdg`

to find out which packages require ruby-xdg. For me it was only tmuxinator. I couldn't see a quick fix, & I use tmux directly, so I just uninstalled tmuxinator & ruby-xdg for now, and I could then complete the AUR upgrade.

Your mileage may vary, but hopefully that'll help you with a way in.